# How to use "Wasting or Wasted"

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, adjectives, american-english

I get a little bit confused when I want to use Wasting or Wasted, because these words are adjectives (just talk about the adjectival aspect).

> The follow sentences are quoted from the movie "Ex machina":
>
> - I told you, you're wasting your time talking to her, however, you wouldn't be **wasting** your time, if you were dancing with her.

I was wondering whether or not I could replace **wasting** by **wasted**?

Comment: It would be a good idea if you search 'second conditional' sentences which deal with unreal or imaginary situations. You'll get your answer.

Comment: In this sentence, "wasting" is not being used as an adjective. It follows the helper verb "to be" to form the present progressive, and the progressive of the modal "would."

Answer (score 1):

used after "be", **wasting** is an active participle: it defines what the subject is doing.

> **you** are wasting your time

used after "be", **wasted** is a passive participle: it defines what is being done to something.

> your **time** is being wasted.

The expression "you are [wasted](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wasted)" can mean two things:

- you have deteriorated physically, for example by illness
- you a over-qualified for the job you are in
- you are incapacitated by alcohol or drugs (slang)